# Candy Crush Soda Saga: Best levels to complete quests

Tags: candy-crush-soda

For example, the "Go Fish" quest requires you to match two fish together, a certain number of times.

I've played levels where there are fish generators next to each other, and a lot of the work of finishing the level is matching the fish together to make "triple fish".  These levels would be ideal for this quest, but I can't remember which ones they were.

Does anyone know which levels I mean?  And do you know any other levels that are very well suited to particular quests?

For example, level 8 is well suited to the "color collecting" quests that require you to match eg 1000 orange candies, since there's a lot of combos on the level and it's quick and easy to complete.

Comment: People we have to regroup! King has switched most of the levels we discussed around so it's hard to find them! Levels 24,62,73, etc are not the same!

Comment: @W.J. sorry, i don't play it any more.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this game, but given @W.J. statement, I've gone ahead and added a bounty in an attempt to get some updated answers.

Answer (score 4):

If you’re pretty far along...
I use 1282 (Persipan Playground) for almost everything. 
1399 (Northern Nibbles) for matching fish with fish. 
Level 5 for coloring candies. You get a free one at the start and can just quit the level and get credit for it. 
425 is in Marshmallow Mine.

Comment: Brilliant tip about level 5, thanks.

Comment: btw I am pretty far along, on 1641 at time of writing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer about the fish, but I use level 8 a lot for all sorts of quests. It is good for making color bombs and special candies.

Comment: Yeah, I tend to use this for color-collecting quests, since it's so easy to complete, and quick.

Answer (score 2):

I think if you should try level 1138 it is very nice to make special candies and bombs
It is hard but It is the best for quests

Comment: BTW, level 1138 is in "Marshmallow Matinee"

Answer (score 2):

Found another one...
Level 24, match the candies in the middle on the bottom two rows, then your next move right above it will be 2 color bombs.

Comment: That is brilliant, thanks!  Was just doing a colorbombs quest as it happens.  You can quit as soon as you get them and they still count.

Comment: You can edit your first answer to include this information instead of posting another.

Comment: I discovered another great thing about Level 24:  if you get an orange candy above the groups-of-five that you're about to match up, in the middle, you get a Color Bomb and a Color Candy, which you can then combine, which is part of one of the quests.

Comment: Another thing - I usually do the set on the left, then the set on the right, and usually on the right I end up with a color bomb next to a striped candy, which is also useful for one of the quests (which requires you to combine color bombs and striped candies).  so #24 is great for several quests.  Thanks again for posting!

Answer (score 1):

The best level I have found in CC Soda Saga is: 425. It has 43 moves and only uses a few colors. Makes lots of wrapped candies/stripped/and color bombs.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know which world it's in?  It's a bit of a PITA to hunt for them.

Comment: It's in Marshmallow Mine btw.

Answer (score 1):

I use **#106** as an ultimate level for completing quests (all various ones).
Whenever I get bored with it, I switch to **#73**.

[image: Candy Crush Soda Saga Level 106]
<sub>Image courtesy of [Wikia](http://candycrushsoda.wikia.com/wiki/Level_106)</sub>

**Level #106** is the 1st level in **Soda Coast** episode, and it meets all requirements for completing quests:

- It is not trivial (e.g., not very "early" level);
- It is easy to win; from personal experience, my success ratio is about 75% on this level, so I can not only complete quests from the right menu (which are awarded even if you die), but also the quests from the left panel (which are only awarded if you win);
- It is long enough (35 moves), which allows me clear up the space in e.g. 20-25 moves and have free moves for fancy stuff like double fish (which does little but is needed for quests);
- It is easy to get at least 2 stars on it (for "blue alien" star quests);
- It quickly opens a free open space that allows me create lots of 5-bar and 6-bar color candies. If you are lucky enough, you can trigger the "chain reaction" of re-coloring 6-bar candies that would let you get a **score of 1,000,000**, with the corresponding amount of various fancy candies generated (check the high scores table, the #1 is me);
- Bonus feature: it is the 1st level in its Episode, so it is easy to navigate. :-)

---

[image: Candy Crush Soda Saga Level #73]
<sub>Image courtesy of [Wikia](http://candycrushsoda.wikia.com/wiki/Level_73)</sub>

**Level #73**  is the 13th level in **Choco Canyon** episode, and it is very similar to #106, but it is harder to win (a "Samurai" hard level). Same "free the bears", same 35 moves.

Comment: Great, thanks!  If it's not too much trouble would you mind editing your answer to say which world it's in?  On the phone version you can't see the level numbers from the world select, just the world names.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, added episode names. FWIW, Wikia refers them as *episodes*, not *worlds*.

Comment: thanks - which Wikia do you mean though?  They're worlds on http://candycrushsoda.wikia.com, eg http://candycrushsoda.wikia.com/wiki/World_Forty-One

Comment: Btw, I just revisited this level and it kind of feels like a less-easy-to-complete version of level 8, in terms of "clear-a-bunch-of-squares-till-you-get-into-chain-reaction-land".  Which reminds me, have you ever had a thing where the game won't let you revisit a level?  Sometimes I try to play level 8 or level 1138 (my two bonus-getting go tos) and it shoves the Modal up which tells you the levels you need to reach to get an award of some powerups.

Comment: I love level #73 now - the fact that it's hard to complete actually makes it better for getting powerups.  What happens with level 8, which is the same but easier, is that you finish it too quickly, and don't get the chance to get as many.  With #73, you get to the "high chance of getting a powerup" part of the proceedings quite quickly, and then stay there for a lot of moves - usually till your moves run out.  It's my favourite one for collecting combos now.  (If i run out of lives I just jump my system clock forward to refill them, then jump it back).  Thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, my mistake on the worlds-v-episodes thing.  An Episode is a group of 15 levels, and has a name, like Persipan Playground, and a world is a group of three episodes.  So, you do navigate to episodes, not worlds.

Comment: @MaxWilliams, if this answer helped you most of all, please consider marking it as "Accepted Answer".

Answer (score 1):

1376 in the Treacle Tunnel episode is great for special candies, bombs, and fish.  Especially color bomb/special candy combos and double fish combos.  It's challenging to finish, though, so it's really only good for completing quests (not the competitions that require you to complete the level).

Comment: Thanks.  Can you edit your answer to say what world that's in?

Comment: Done! added episode & more detail.

Comment: great, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Level **1564**, in the **Castle of Semla** episode, is good for **matching fish with fish**, since it has a row of fish generators next to each other.  You need to clear them first though, since there's initially a barrier under each fish generator, but the top section is easy to generate vertical striped candies to clear the barriers.  I can usually get at least 4 or 5 per run-through.  It's hard to complete, though, especially if you're focussed on matching fish rather than clearing the honey.

Answer (score 0):

451 is a fun one that will get you fish.  Sprinkleshell does all the work.  After getting your first "eat", just continue having him eat the blue ones over and over again.

It's in Ice Pop Pools.

Answer (score -2):

Level 929 is good for Go Fish. It's in Peppermint Province.

Comment: Thanks - would you mind adding what episode that's in?